# Not everywhere seen

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> Known for being worth more than three cats,
>   though my true beginning lies in seeking greater power.
>   Contrary to popular belief I never needed to begin.
>   On the front page you may get a sizzler,
>   but seek me with your voice to receive unlimited free queries

What am I?

Hint:

> I can't exist in a world without order and direction

Hint 2:

> I am known for being worth three and a third cats to be more precise

Comment: Don't know why there are downvotes as you have a good track record for puzzles and this seems like a good one. +1 from me.

Comment: just wanted to clarify - the last line says you receive "unlimited free queries". Does that mean you can ask it unlimited queries, or does it return queries when you talk to it?

Comment: Probably 'The Bible'.. maybe worth more than 3 cats.. and sizzler like font used on front page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is

> [image]

aka the

> Konami Code

Known for being worth more than three cats,

> In Contra (and Gradius II), entering the code at the title screen starts the player with thirty lives (if a cat has nine lives, that's three and a third cats, as per Hint 2).

though my true beginning lies in seeking greater power.

> The first ever use of the code in Gradius, entered when paused, activates a bunch of power-ups.

Contrary to popular belief I never needed to begin.

> I think this refers to the fact that you didn't have to press the start button also for the cheat to work, just the buttons above. I believe this was a common misconception.

On the front page you may get a sizzler,

> Entering the Konami code on the front page of reddit will cause a small throwing star made of bacon to fly across your screen.

but seek me with your voice to receive unlimited free queries

> A Google voice search for the Konami code unlocks a hidden cheat mode where a voice declares "Cheat mode unlocked: Unlimited free Google searches."

Hint 1

> The code involves directional buttons pressed in a specific order.

Comment: This is correct, though the first clue is about Contra, the most well known use of the code

Answer (score 5):

I don't really believe this -- there's too much I don't have a good fit for -- but could you possibly be

> Google?

Known for being worth more than three cats,

> Absolutely no idea, though Google (now Alphabet) is worth an awful lot. Maybe there's some famously valuable company with a catty name that's out-capitalized 3x by Google, or something.

though my true beginning lies in seeking greater power.

> "Google" is a misspelling (accidental at first but deliberately embraced, I think) of "googol", a number equal to $10^{100}$, a large *power* of 10.

Contrary to popular belief I never needed to begin.

> Numbers, unlike material things like people and galaxies, are timeless. (But this doesn't quite work: perhaps *a googol* is timeless, but Google isn't the same thing.)

On the front page you may get a sizzler,

> The front page of Google's search results often has something striking or witty commemorating a particular occasion or person.

but seek me with your voice to receive free queries

> If you have an Android phone you can say "OK, Google" to it followed by asking it to do things -- including, e.g., search-engine queries.

Comment: Good attempt, though this is not the correct answer

Comment: I'd have been disappointed if it were! But perhaps having a wrong answer out there will encourage someone else to figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to take a shot in the dark here.

I believe that the answer is

> TIME

I have no idea about the cat part, but for seeking greater power

> early calendars were based on religious beliefs (think mayans)

Contrary to popular belief I never needed to begin.

> beginning of time, big bang, etc., etc. were random events

On the front page you may get a sizzler,

> Time magazine often displays attractive actors/actresses, celebrities, etc. on their cover

but seek me with your voice to receive free queries

> say "What's the time?" in any populated area and you're bound to get an answer

Comment: Good attempt, but not the correct answer

Comment: Oh well, I tried. Fantastic riddle!

Answer (score 1):

> Series, although I can't follow some of the clues.

"Known for being worth more than three cats"

> a straight is worth more than three of a kind?

"though my true beginning lies in seeking greater power"

> series are useful for calculating e.g., integrals.

"Contrary to popular belief I never needed to begin."

> you have have a series with no first element.

"On the front page you may get a sizzler"

> don't know.

"but seek me with your voice to receive unlimited free queries"

> a reference to Apple's Siri.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling. Could you please edit your answer to show your thought process and/or explanations as to how it fits the clues (at least as far as you know)?

Comment: This is not the correct answer

Comment: Rats! I'll keep thinking about it, thanks.